# WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. At a loss as to what is happening

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I've been using webdriver.Firefox() for years now, today I started another project and `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` is returning

```
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I have tried adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` to my PATH. I have tried `pip install -U selenium`. I've tried

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\8u2w2ge1.Me")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

I have added the addon checkcompatibility to my firefox addons. Nothing, nothing is working, same error, Python 2.7.11, Windows 10 x64

This is the general traceback I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpwvgny8 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Anyone know why it is having issues creating this profile in the temp directory? Some new way to force it to profiles that exist, because my old method is not working.

Comment: You need  to try adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` to path without the exe.

Comment: What is the result of `>dir c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpwvgny8`?

Comment: Is it expecting profile from this address:  Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpwvgny8 ?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I removed the firefox.exe I got the same result. It is a folder that looks very similar to my normal profile, save all the addon stuff.

Comment: @AbirKhan I believe it is and when I look, the profile folder is there.

Comment: If you take profile from this location: c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpwvgny8, will it solve your problem?

Comment: @AbirKhan all the profiles for firefox store themselves in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*` where * are flies like 2sdf23.default, 12df345.Me and other profiles I have created from running firefox.exe -p. I have tried loading direct profiles like this, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a work around for this, it isn't perfect and I actually use chrome through chromedriver, since it is a bit more stable, but to use firefox you might want to download a geckodriver and include it in your system path or path to it in your setup of the browser, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, seems to be where they keep releases, chrome has a [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) that functions and is used in much the same way. I am not sure why we need these new drivers to use selenium in windows, but such is life, hopes this saves someone else some work.